# Mask URL - ASP.Net 3.5

Tags: .net, asp.net, c#-3.0

I have hosted a site in a shared server, let me call as Server-X. 
My domain (ie. www.examplesite.com) is from another server, called Server-Y. 
I have changes the name server of my domain to point to the server-X. So that my website is alive and I can access the database and all works fine.

The problem is it is showing that the site physical address as SERVER-X. I wanted that to be hidden/masked.

In other words, where ever I navigate in the site, the addressbar should show "www.examplesite.com" and NOT "www.examplesite.com/myprofile.aspx"

Thanks in advance.

-Sabarish

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to rewrite the url then you can use

http://www.urlrewriting.net/149/en/home.html

A cool opensource url rewriter module